# Relative File Paths not getting detected when I deploy my app to Google Cloud platform

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, filepath

Locally everything works fine, however as soon as I deploy my app to App Engine. Relative File paths are not getting picked up by google cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Where to put your static files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/static-content),

> You must put your static served files within your app's webapp directory. You can use folders, but remember that all file paths and URIs are relative to the webapp directory.
>
> After you choose a location for the static files, you must define their location in the appengine-web.xml file, using the  element.

An example how to configure this is:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <static-files>
    <include path="/**.html" >
    </include>
  </static-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Also, in the doc: [Serving files directly from your app]
(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/serving-static-files#serving_from_your_application), it mentions:

> To serve static files for Java 11 in the standard environment, you define the handlers in your app.yaml file using either the static_dir or static_files elements.

For example, the following line instructs the browser to load the  `main.css` file:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
```

The `./public` directory is defined in the `static_dir` element of the project's `app.yaml` file:

```
handlers:
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: favicon.ico

  - url: /static
    static_dir: public

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

Comment: Your answer has been extremely helpful, I have followed the documentation that allows you to specify static files in a spring app on app engine in which they required me to add this `entrypoint: java -noverify BOOT-INF/resources/:BOOT-INF/classes/:BOOT-INF/lib/* com.mycompany.myapp.YOUAPPCLASSNAME` to my app.yaml file however I can't seem to figure out what does `com.mycompany.myapp.YOUAPPCLASSNAME`stands for as I did copy the reference package to my main class but it did not work and the app fails to deploy because of it. Thanks for your help man in advance.

Comment: Glad to read it is helpful;  as per my understanding, `com.mycompany.myapp.YOUAPPCLASSNAME` should be the classPath of the class you would like to serve (JAR file that contains all your app's classes).  If there is no class I think you can dismiss that part. Please let me know if this works :)

Comment: ANSWER: went with a different approach just use this call to serve static files: `  InputStream serviceAccount = new ClassPathResource("firebase.json").getInputStream();